# Objective C: How to resolve 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error

Tags: objective-c, ios, unrecognized-selector

I am trying to access a property of instance object using the following code

```
for (User *user in likersArray) 
{
    //Set variables for dictionary
    NSString *nameLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",[user.nickname length]];
}
```

However, I keep getting the following error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[NSCFString nickname]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8c0f780'
```

My user class is defined as below

```
@interface User : NSObject <NSCoding>
{
NSString *uid;
NSString *name;
NSString *nickname;
}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *uid;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *name;
@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *nickname;

@end
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

That error means that not everything in your `likersArray` is a `User` object.  At least one thing in there is an `NSString`.

Answer (score 5):

It could also mean that one of the `User` objects in `likersArray` is being over-released and you are hitting garbage.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very similar issue which was being caused due to only one item being created and inserted into the array. If your likersArray contains only 1 item it causes this error as well and it's a nasty bug to find. Hopefully this helps someone!