# iOS app crashing with error: NSCFNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString: unrecognized selector sent to instance

Tags: ios, objective-c, unrecognized-selector

Our iOS app terminates with an error of `[__NSCFNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1755e090`.

We're testing on an iPhone 5 w iOS 7.

It crashes on this line: `[self parseDictionary:notificationMessage intoJSON:jsonStr]`.

Method containing this line:

```
- (void)notificationReceived {
    NSLog(@"Notification received");

    if (notificationMessage && self.callback)
    {
        NSMutableString *jsonStr = [NSMutableString stringWithString:@"{"];

        [self parseDictionary:notificationMessage intoJSON:jsonStr];

        if (isInline)
        {
            [jsonStr appendFormat:@"foreground:\"%d\"", 1];
            isInline = NO;
        }
        else
            [jsonStr appendFormat:@"foreground:\"%d\"", 0];

        [jsonStr appendString:@"}"];

        NSLog(@"Msg: %@", jsonStr);

        NSString * jsCallBack = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@(%@);", self.callback, jsonStr];
        [self.webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:jsCallBack];

        self.notificationMessage = nil;
    }
}

-(void)parseDictionary:(NSDictionary *)inDictionary intoJSON:(NSMutableString *)jsonString
{
    NSArray         *keys = [inDictionary allKeys];
    NSString        *key;

    for (key in keys)
    {
        id thisObject = [inDictionary objectForKey:key];

        if ([thisObject isKindOfClass:[NSDictionary class]])
            [self parseDictionary:thisObject intoJSON:jsonString];
        else
            [jsonString appendFormat:@"\"%@\":\"%@\",",
             key,
             [[[[inDictionary objectForKey:key]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"]
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""]
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"]];
    }
}
```

Stack trace (along with one debugging line to show the variable value):

```
2014-01-07 16:32:36.980 Wopple[195:60b] Notification received
Printing description of self->notificationMessage:
{
    "_" = "gHf8EeO3_ZDiugJkgA";
    aps =     {
        alert = "hi foo bar right";
        badge = 3;
    };
}
2014-01-07 16:33:22.774 Wopple[195:60b] -[__NSCFNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1755e090
2014-01-07 16:33:22.776 Wopple[195:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFNumber stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:withString:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x1755e090'
*** First throw call stack:
(0x308c3e83 0x3ac246c7 0x308c77b7 0x308c60af 0x30814dc8 0x88da5 0x88d1f 0x88915 0x8757b 0x3335ec93 0x3335f75d 0x340d0b37 0x3088e777 0x3088e713 0x3088cedf 0x307f7471 0x307f7253 0x3552b2eb 0x330ac845 0x7f5d3 0x3b11dab7)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
```

Comment: Since the problem happens in your `parseDictionary:intoJSON:` method it would make sense to post that relevant code. From the error it is obvious that you are calling an `NSString` method on an object you think is a string but is really an `NSNumber`.

Comment: oops, you're right. updated with parseDictionary code.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Objective C: How to resolve 'unrecognized selector sent to instance' error](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6722149/objective-c-how-to-resolve-unrecognized-selector-sent-to-instance-error)

Comment: Why not just use NSJSONSerialization to turn your dictionary into an NSData instance and then into an NSString? It takes care of parsing types correctly, and is probably more efficient that manually writing a JSON Serialiser.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using:

```
[[[[inDictionary objectForKey:key]
               stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\" withString:@"\\\\"]
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\"" withString:@"\\\""]
                stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\n" withString:@"\\n"]];
```

You're assuming that `objectForKey` is going to return an `NSString` object. But, in the case where your app is crashing, the object returned is actually an `NSNumber`.

You should use `isKindOfClass:` to determine the object type, or use `stringValue` on your `NSNumber` to get a string representation of the object.

Comment: Do not use `description`. That is only for debugging purposes.

Comment: sorry, we're new to objective-c. this is actually a phonegap plug-in we're debugging. how are we supposed to determine the object type and adjust the method?